# Check if a process is running as Administrator/Elevated from another application - Windows 10

Tags: c#, vb.net

[image]Is there a way to check if an existing process is already running as Administrator/Elevated from a VB .Net WinForm application? I have a utility which connects to the Main application via API. This was all working fine on Windows 7 but on Windows 10, my utility was unable to connect to the main program via API. I tired lots of things but nothing worked. Finally I found that if I run the main program As Administrator, the my API utility worked/connected just like that. I reviewed the documentation for Process class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2) but can't find anything obvious to elevated execution property. Any advise or code snippet would be appreciated.

In Windows 10 Task Manager, you can see if the process is running as Elevated or Not. I just need something to capture this in the code.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing around I found that after adding app.manifest file with below settings and adding a property IsElevated in the code, I could see if the exe is running as Elevated or not in Task manager. Hope this can help anyone looking for similar matter.

from app.manifest file:

> ```
> <security>
>   <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
>     <!-- UAC Manifest Options
>          If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
>          requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.
>
>     <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
>     <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
>     <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
>
>         Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
>         Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
>         compatibility.
>     -->
>     <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
>   </requestedPrivileges>
> </security>
> ```

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsElevated As Boolean
    Get
        Return New WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
    End Get
End Property
```

When using in the code:

```
If IsElevated = True Then
                Me.Text = "TEST Utility - Administrator (Elevated)"
            End If
            If IsElevated = False Then
                Me.Text = "TEST Utility - Normal (Non-Elevated)"
            End If
```